# Forcing XP style DPI scaling through a VB 2010 application?

Tags: gui, high-dpi, vb.net

I have an app in vb.net 2010. on a windows 7 machine, the UI appears ok for up to 120 dpi (125%) since windows 7 by default enables "xp style dpi scaling" for dpi values equal or less than 120. for >120 dpi values the UI objects get misaligned and blurry unless user manually check (enable) the "xp style dpi scaling" option in display settings. for the same reason, the ".DpiX" returns correct number for <=120 dpi, while returns 96 for any >120 dpi value, unless, again, i manually enable that option.

I am wondering if there is any way *for example, through manifest) to force windows use the XP style dpi scaling for every dpi value?

Comment: i just found out that what "xp style dpi scaling" actually does is disabling "dpi virtualization". so, i am basically looking for a way to disable dpi virtualization through my code/manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following setting in your manifest

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

If you wish to change Windows' settings, you will have to manipulate the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI` registry key.

If font scaling is critical for your application, consider rendering your own text and scale it using [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: thanks hanxue. but i had tried this before and got the same results. i think your comment is regarding declaring the app dpi-aware, while my problem is due to dpi virtualization.

Comment: @Ali even changing the registry key to get Windows to use xp style dpi scaling does not work?